# Jupyter center only print output

Tags: jupyter, jupyter-lab

How can I make a print output (but not other outputs like plots etc.) centered? For example this code:

```
print("I want this text centered")
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using HTML, then you can center text as follows:

```py
from IPython.core.display import display, HTML

content = "Hello World"
display(HTML(f"<div style='text-align:center'>{content}</div>"))
```

Which will produce the following:
[image]

You can also create a re-useable function that can be used instead of print:

```py
def centered(content):
    display(HTML(f"<div style='text-align:center'>{content}</div>"))
```

Which would be used as follows:

```py
centered("My centered text.")
```

And produces:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

`<h1><center>Centered text!</center></h1>`

Comment: The `<center>` element has been obsolete for many years. Do not use the `<center>` element!